# Find unique elements from the given array and print them

Tags: c++

#### Question: Find unique elements from the given array and print them

I have dry run below given code many times but i am not getting what is the problem in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void findingUniqueElement(int array[], int size)
{
    int brray[100];
    int count = 0;
    bool equal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        equal = 0;
        int value = array[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (i != j && value == array[j])
            {
                equal = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (equal == 0)
        {
            brray[i] = value;
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << brray[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 7};
    findingUniqueElement(arr, 6);
}
```

i was expecting as an output

```
1 5 3 7
```

but when i run the code, getting as output

```
1 1877357483 1878039440 5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Change barray[i]=value to `barray[count]=value`

Comment: just a guess. `brray[i] = value;` should be ` brray[count] = value;`. At least that would make use of some otherwise unues `count`.

Comment: what do you mean with "I have dry run many times" ? Use a debugger to spot this kind of issues

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran can you please tell me reason for that. It will be more useful

Comment: Uninitialised memory slots, when accessed will give you such garbage numbers. You inspect every element, but fill the array `barray` using the counter variable i, instead of `count`

Comment: Btw, you should not allocate 100 elements for `barray`, it is sufficient to do `int[] barray = new int[size]`, so allocate that much actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! Here is the code modified by me:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void findingUniqueElement(int array[], int size) {
  int brray[100];
  memset(brray, 0, 100);         // modified here
  int count = 0;
  bool equal = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    equal = 0;
    int value = array[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      if (i != j && value == array[j]) {
        equal = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (equal == 0) {
      brray[i] = value;
      count++;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // modified here
    if (brray[i] != 0)  // modified here
      cout << brray[i] << " ";
  }
}

int main() {
  int arr[6] = {1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 7};
  findingUniqueElement(arr, 6);
}
```

I modified three places in your code:

1. You should initialize `brray` when you declare it, the strange values output are because they were in the memory when you defined `brray`, you should clean the memory before you use it.
2. The way you store unique number in `brray` is not very correct, when `array[i]` is not unique, you will add `i`, which leave `0` at `brray[i]`, so to fit your code, you should make i from 0 to size. To get more clear about what I'm talking about, you can check the memory of `brray`.
3. Since I assume there is no `0` in your test data, so if there is a `0` in `barray`, you know it is not a valid value, just skip it. Also, you can use a more elegant way to do this, like @Anand Sowmithiran commented:

```cpp
int brray[100];
memset(brray, 0, 100);
int count = 0;

for (/* conditions... */) {
    // if there is a unique number
    brray[count++] = unique_number;
}

for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    cout << brray[index] << " ";
}
```

Hope my answer is helpful!